# bash autocompletion scripts in OS X

Tags: bash, auto-complete

Here is what I learned so far:

```
# settings on mac
if [[ $(uname) == "Darwin" ]]; then
    # enable bash completion
    if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion ]; then
            . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion
    fi
    # enable git completion
    if [ -f `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
    . `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
    fi
fi
```

What if I have multiple scripts in  `` `brew --prefix`/etc/bash_completion.d/ ``? How can I enable all of them?

Or, is there a folder in OS X equivalent to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` in linux?

Comment: The file, `bash_completion` that you're sourcing handles the sourcing of the individual files from the `bash_completion.d` directory.